# Nativescript fs module not seeing folder or files

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using the Nativescript tutorial for creating a carousel [here](https://github.com/sajjaphani/nativescript-carousel-ng).

The problem I'm running into is that I get the following error (minus my obfuscation)

```
Error: Failed to load component from module: undefined.xml or file: /data/data/{Obfuscated}/files/app/pages/welcome/slides/slide1.xml
```

when it tries to load xml files on this line (full snippet below):

```
slides.push(builder.load(slidePath))
```

Upon some inspection I found that it's the file system that doesn't see the files I'm loading. My code is the same as the tutorials code.  I've gone through it line by line (even doing a diff) and the code is in fact the same.

Here's a better look at the file path it's choking on, you can compare that to the image I provided below:
**/data/data/{Obfuscated}/files/app/pages/welcome/slides/slide1.xml**

I can verify that the folder structure is the same as in the tutorial `app/pages/welcome/slides.slide1.xml` but when the page loads, I get that error and it never loads the xml.

Here's the full snippet:

```
private loadSlides(slideFiles, slidesPath) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const slides = []
      const currentAppFolder = fs.knownFolders.currentApp();
      const path = fs.path.normalize(currentAppFolder.path + "/" + slidesPath);
      slideFiles.forEach((dataFile, i) => {
        const slidePath = path + "/" + dataFile;
        console.log(slidePath);
        // Here's where it crashes
        slides.push(builder.load(slidePath))
      });

      resolve(slides);
    });
  }
```

When I test it out by debugging and using the file-system module to test whether the path exists... it always comes back false, even though the folder structure definitely exists the way it does in the tutorial.

The console.log line displays this:

```
/data/data/{myobfuscation}/files/app/pages/welcome/slides
```

As you can see it matches my folder path below.

**How do I get the file-system to see that folder structure?**  It works just fine when I use it for verifying the existence image files.

Here's an image of the folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Are you running with `--bundle` flag, try without `--bundle` and see if that helps.

Comment: I just tested your suggestion but it results in the same error with or without the flag.  Good thinking though.

Comment: @iamjc015 / razorsyntax Can you share a sample repo where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: I wish I could (security reasons where I work).  That said, I copied the code directly, including the modules, components, file paths, and etc and went so far as matching package.json with the same versions as the demo.  But I don't believe it has to do with the demo, per se, as I think it has to do with file-system not seeing the file path.

Comment: It has nothing to do with file-system, the only possible reason is that you are not looking at right path / the build doesn't include that file, for either of the cases I may need a sample project.

Comment: Okay, I'll test out the file path then and see if that's it.  There's no way for me to share our codebase (without causing HR/Management panic... lol) but if you'd like to test out the code I'm basing it from you can find the project here: https://github.com/sajjaphani/nativescript-carousel-ng

Keep in mind that the code is identical between our project and the code in this repo as far as modules, components, file paths, routes, and even the code in the welcome.component.ts file.

Comment: Just noticed you are using Angular, webpack will never know that you need the XML files in slides folder so it will never make it to bundle. You will have to adjust to `webpack.config.js` to include the slides folder in the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack will never know you would require those XML files at runtime, you will have to adjust `webpack.config.js` to include those files in the bundle.

Update the `CopyWebpackPlugin` configuration as follows,

```
        // Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
        new CopyWebpackPlugin(
            [
                { from: { glob: "assets/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.xml" } },
            ],
            { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] },
        ),
```

Adding `{ from: { glob: "**/*.xml" } },` copies all XML files along with folder structure into the bundle.

Comment: That was exactly it!  That also explains other issues we were having with loading images that were not .png or .jpg.  Thank's Manoj!