# ui/builder load() returns undefined

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have a function like this:

```
      private loadSlides(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          const slideViews = []


 slideViews.push(builder.load(__dirname + '/app/dashboard/customer-product-slide.xml'));

          resolve(slideViews);
        });
      }
```

builder.load() returns undefined. Why is that so?

Note: I verified that the file actually exists on device explorer.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486846/nativescript-fs-module-not-seeing-folder-or-files

Comment: There is no answer either on that post.

Comment: Creating random posts one after another is not going to help. You got to give it at least some time for answers.

Comment: Yep, didn't see it was posted just today. What a coincidence.

Comment: You can mark this as duplicate.